# Jquery plugin allow multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html5boilerplate, boilerplate

I'm using the jQuery [boilerplate template](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js) for a plugin I'm writing. It basically just runs an ajax call and replaces the content of the element it has running on. Example:

My plugin name is `'getContent'`

```
$('.container').getContent({
    html : 'foo'
});
```

Very simplified version of the plugin, however right at the very bottom of the template there is this:

```
// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
        }
    });

    // chain jQuery functions
    return this;
};
```

Obviously it does some checks to see if the pluginName is already bound to the element. In this case it is, and the plugin doesn't run when you try to do it again later on in the same page instance.

Is the correct way to fix my issue to literally just remove the if around the `new Plugin` section?

Answer (score 0):

in order to be able to able to run the plugin for multiple instances you need to have a new closure for each instance, try the code below:

```
function getContentFunc(elem,options){
    //things you want your plugin to do
};

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    if ($.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) return;
    return $(this).each(function() {
        getContentFunc(this,options);
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);
    });
};
```

see a very simple plugin, done with the same method **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/258W6/)**

Comment: This doesn't work sorry, if I add a console log into your shorten function it only fires once.

Comment: well of course it fires once because we only have one `p` tag in the code, copy the same `p` tag and add the `console.log()` and see that it is fired twice!

Comment: What if I wanted to run it on the same p tag though?

Comment: well for the shorten example it wouldn't make sense to do so, but if you wanna do such thing you have to delete the `if` and the `$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);`